# Increment value in column in an SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i have the following case to resolve.
I have a table with the following structure and i need to do the column Comment3 incremented by 1 but not for whole the records, but only for the records that are matched based on the Tid column.

So my table looks like this

```
------------------------
ID  |  TID  |  COMMENT3   
------------------------
101 |  715  |  1
102 |  715  |  2
103 |  715  |  NULL
104 |  715  |  NULL
```

So i need every null value in column Comment3 to get updated with the last value plus 1, based on the TID which is the reference column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ANd what SQL engine do you use?

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: SQL Management Studio @juergend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ROW_NUMBER()` with the proper `OVER` clause:

```
;WITH Comment3NewRanking AS
(
    SELECT
        T.ID,
        T.TID,
        T.Comment3,
        Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.TID ORDER BY T.ID ASC)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
)
UPDATE C SET
    Comment3 = C.Ranking
FROM
    Comment3NewRanking AS C
WHERE
    C.Comment3 IS NULL
```

This solution assumes that whenever the IDs are set for a particular `TID`, they are in ascending `ID` order. Also assuming you want values from 1 onwards on each tier of `TID` (if not please supply another representative example).

Comment: That was what i was looking for!
Thank you very much!